# I have an issue in changing the site address url

Tags: wordpress

I have recently changed my site to WP and now the site is accessible only at example.com, but the www.example.com has high page authority and linking domains. When I tried to change the site address url from example.com to www.example.com then the site is not accessible. What might be the reason behing this? what can I do to bring back my old url?

Answer (score 0):

Check your DNS servers. A CNAME record may have gone walkabout.

Here's a table representation:

```
Record Type  |  URL / Address  |  IP Address
---------------------------------------------
     A       |   example.com   |   10.0.0.0
   CNAME     | www.example.com |  example.com
```

Comment: i have tested it using leaf DNS. The results was like in the above table.

Comment: Yes tried except the 3rd one. I installed WP following these steps http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory My WP url is http://example.com/wordpress and site address url is http://example.com I tried changing the site url to www.example.com then it shows 404. Then by using the Cpanel settings the site is back but still cannot add www

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues:

1. Database: Look for table `wp_options`, there is field `siteurl`  -
   try to play with it.
2. .htaccess:

   ```
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stackoverflow\.com
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.stackoverflow.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
   ```

   OR

   ```
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stackoverflow\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.stackoverflow.com/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```
3. [Clear your DNS](http://www.tech-faq.com/how-to-flush-dns.html)